# Prevent a WordPress theme from updating

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We've inherited a WordPress theme that's a heavily customized version of the [Responsive](http://themeid.com/responsive-theme/) wordpress theme. But the author never changed the theme meta info, so it still shows up as "Responsive theme" in the WordPress backend, with a link to update it, etc.

I want to change the theme from "Responsive" to "Responsive - Customized" and disable the update link so that the changes don't get blown out. I know how to change the theme title/info in the style sheet, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the theme's update functionality?

The link:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change theme title/info as you said but also try changing theme folder name.

Comment: Marko- ok it seems changing the folder prevents the update, but do you know where the update logic actually is- (for some reason changing the folder is breaking other parts of the theme, so id like to just kill the update logic in code specifically)

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that. Have you reselected the theme in appearance -> themes?

Comment: You'd have to hack wordpress itself... The only thing that should be breaking is the menu, but all you need to do is setup the menus again (Appearance > Menus). What else is breaking?

Comment: sorry guys you're right- was just some hardcoded image urls that shouldn't have been there

Comment: I tried this and it lost the theme configurations as well like logo, colour theme, etc. Lesson learned - fork your theme at the start. I've just gone with renaming it in `style.css` and removing the url which I think will stop it being able to find updates?